# How to detach a thread on Windows C++

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading

How to detach a thread on windows in `C++`. On `Posix` we have `pthread_detach(pthread_self());`. How to achieve this in windows enviornment.

Comment: is the windows implementation of pthreads different than the *nix one, in this respect?

Comment: I want to say "DeleteFiber", but trying to remember equivalencies that may not exist is evading me. For more on that topic, though here's the link to what MSDN has on threads: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682556%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: what's wrong with `std::thread::detach()`?

Comment: What do you mean by saying detach? If it's about forcing thread to stop running insturctions, delete it stack and registers set -- `TerminateThread` is the answer or 1std::thread::detach()`.

Comment: @Apokal `TerminateThread`, which, well, terminates a thread, is definitely **not** the same as detaching the thread. Detaching is more about saying you don't really care about the thread resource and want it to be cleaned up automatically once the thread has finished naturally, but without the need for explicitly joining it.

Comment: @ChristianRau I agree with you. `TerminateThread` terminates a thread, and `thread::detach` means detaching from a c++ object. So that's why I asked him to clarify a question. Maybe he asked one thing, while thinking about another.

Comment: @KerrekSB Hah, nice one! Though I guess he's talking about Win32 threads (even if not stated clearly in the question).

Comment: @Apokal Well, the use of the word *"detach"* (which doesn't only have the respective meaning in C++11 threads) and the reference to `pthread_detach` makes it quite clear that he's not talking about thread termination.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Yes, in the sense that there isn't any, at least not a builtin one (why do I have the suspicion that you already know this?).

Comment: @ChristianRau; hm. well i googled up (http://sources.redhat.com/pthreads-win32/). i've implemented my own higher level threads both in windows and on single-board computers, but i'm not very familiar with pthreads. i only know that they were considered and dismissed by the boost folks. general state for windows is that reportedly both g++ 4.7 and msvc 11 support c++11 threads; i have both compilers but have not had time to play around with it. :-(

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Assuming that you are using [_beginthreadex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdzttdcb.aspx) or `CreateThread` to create the thread, you just need to close the thread handle using [CloseHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724211.aspx).

Comment: I was a little uneasy when I saw this answer, as I would expect that Close also terminates the thread. This passage from MSDN makes things clear, though:  

'Closing a thread handle does not terminate the associated thread or remove the thread object. (...) To remove a thread object, you must terminate the thread, then close all handles to the thread.'